# Set default image for a person in Photos

Tags: macos, ios, photos

There is [one question that has an answer that seems to mention a process for this in a previous version of Photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257385/how-to-change-default-memories-photo-in-apple-photo-app/257397#257397), but I'm not seeing how to do this in Photos now (version 5.0 on macOS and whatever it is on iOS 13.2)

Comment: oh... actually that process mentioned in the other question's answer works, but only on iOS

Comment: aren't our your iOS and macOS photos in sync ?

Comment: Thats a good question... I'll say "~"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to people tab and open the person you're wanting to change the key photo of. Find two tabs "Photos" and "Faces".

> [image]

In Faces, find the face you want, right click and in the end, choose "Make Key photo".

Comment: there it is... Why do they hide it under so many layers?

Comment: They trust their system to catch the most smiley face by itself :)

Comment: It’s literally the first... a bunch of my friends hate their pictures :-)